# Recovering a failed Commerce installation

Tags: 8, commerce, installation, wsod

Scenario:

- existing site
- 1G PHP memory
- install commerce modules locally
- do some dev and configuring
- cex my config and deploy upstream
- deployment fails with "php out of memory"
- try deployment again (4 times)
- eventually "succeeds"

Failure:

- "Success" is actually a farce.
- Drupal config shows commerce* modules as installed, but the commerce database tables don't exist.
- "drush pmi" reports modules as not installed
- "drush en" reports modules as already installed
- "drush pmu" fatals with "missing database tables"

Any tips on recovering from this? I need to preserve all my existing content and whatnot.

Comment: What deployment?

Comment: i'm deploying config from my local development setup, where i have created product types, checkout workflows, enabled modules, etc.

Comment: "deployment fails with php out of memory" - What deployment *exactly*? What commands did you use before that exception got raised?

Comment: initially "drush en" fails with memory error. latest errors are about missing tables included in module schema. drush reports that module is not installed, but enabling fails.

Comment: `drush en` what? It's really difficult to help you with that little information you are providing only bit-by-bit. You should give us a complete report to make that a reproducible problem. Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how i fixed the issue. This was a Drupal Commerce problem, but I think the general process could be applicable to other failed module installations:

- Identify module which failed to install correctly (commerce_product)
- Spin up a new vanilla Drupal site, and install the missing module (and its dependencies). In the case of limited resources, Drupal Commerce may need to be enabled one module at a time.
- After enabling the module successfully on the vanilla site, identify the database tables which exist in vanilla but not in the corrupted site. (In my case, there were 9 commerce_product* tables)
- Create those tables on the corrupted site manually: do a `mysqldump --no-data` against the vanilla site, then import it to the corrupt site.
- Now uninstall, then re-install the failed module from the corrupted site.